# Flutter command to delete packages in .pub-cache folder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages, flutter-pub

How to delete the flutter packages in `.pub-cache` folder? When we give `flutter clean`, it will delete the build folder in the current directory. We can delete it manually, but my requirement is to delete the packages in `.pub-cache` folder using the command.

Answer (score 75):

To clear the global PUB_CACHE, run:

```dart
dart pub cache clean
```

or

```dart
flutter pub cache clean
```

Comment: This command was added in Dart 2.14.0 https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: ```flutter pub cache clean``` also works

Comment: @ThongMTruong Yeah, most Dart commands work with Flutter tools also.

Comment: this answer should be marked as correct!

Answer (score 35):

If a dependency is removed from the pubspec and then `pub get` is run, it removes the dependency from the .packages file, making the dependency unavailable for importing.

If a packages in your pub cache to change or break, you can use `flutter pub cache repair` command performs a clean reinstall of all hosted and git packages in the system cache.

Answer (score 31):

**Short answer**

Delete the `pubspec.lock` file then run the command `flutter pub get` again.

**Long Story**

- the command `flutter pub get` will regenerate the `pubspec.lock`.
- In case your code isn't tracked by a source code version control like `git`, make sure to take a backup copy from your `pubspec.lock` file before deleting it especially if the project is a bit old and you are using `caret constraint` for package depencedy and not using `concrete versions` in `pubspec.ymal`
- if the project didn't compile after applying the answer it could be `caret constraint` issue so you have to update your project to match the new  library version or use `concrete versions` in `pubspec.ymal`
  for example

```
dependencies:
  path: 1.3.0
```

Comment: This file should be pushed to the source control, how should removing it be a good solution?

Comment: The command `flutter pub get` will regenerate that file again, don't worry

Comment: Then what is the purpose of checking this file to the source control? Something does not make sense in that.

Comment: Keeping `pubspec.lock`  in source control is optional but; It would be helpful if the project is a bit old and you are using `caret constraint` for package depencedy and not using `concrete versions`  in `pubspec.ymal` which would cause other developers to get newer versions in the  `pubspec.lock` which may cause compilation issues.

Comment: Aah ok, that makes sense now, thanks Shady! But nevertheless, I may end up getting a newer version if I use the `caret`, which will encourage me to not remove this file :D

Comment: You are welcome, Yes you are right; that's why you may need to keep a backup from your original `pubspec.lock` before you delete it if it isn't tracked by a source code version control :D  I will add it as a note in the answer.

Answer (score 14):

Just go to the terminal and type the command

```
flutter pub remove package_name
```

as like

```
flutter pub remove flutter_riverpod
```

Answer (score 5):

It took me more than 3 days to try  all differently way. But finally I found, you need to go into the "pubspec.lock" file. Then go to the library and change the version there. Then go back to the file "pubspec.yaml" and run **Packages get** and it succeeds.

Answer (score 5):

Opening a file explorer and deleting the `.pub-cache` directory in your home folder is pretty easy. Or you can use a normal command line command:

```sh
rm -r ~/.pub-cache
```

Next time you run

```
flutter pub get
```

This will redownload the packages specified in your project's **pubspec.lock** file. If you also delete pubspec.lock then `flutter pub get` will get the most recent non-breaking versions based on your **pubspeck.yaml** file.

#### Notes:

- Any global Pub packages are also stored in the `.pub-cache` folder, so you'll have to install them again, too, whenever you need them next.
- Depending on what you want to do, you probably don't need to delete `.pub-cache`. That's why there isn't a specific command for it. The only reason I can think of is if you want to save space by deleting the old versions of packages that you aren't using any more.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove everything inside your cache folder to reclaim extra disk space or remove problematic packages:

```
flutter pub cache clean && flutter pub get
```

To reinstall all packages in the system cache

```
flutter pub cache repair
```