# Azure pipeline is using cached version of Flutter webview package

Tags: xcode, flutter, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, flutterwebviewplugin

**Local specs:**

MacOS v13.0.1

xCode 14.1

I've a flutter project that uses Flutter InAppWebview package

> flutter_inappwebview: ^5.7.1

, and its working as expected, but when I'm trying to build the project using Azure pipeline, I get this error:

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot call value of non-function type 'String?'
/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Flutter/3.3.8/macos/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.7.1+2/ios/Classes/MyCookieManager.swift:293:43
```

As you can see, the pipeline is using another version from flutter_inappwebview package which is **5.7.1+2** !

Any idea why or how I can reset this .pub-cache on the azure pipeline?

Comment: The XCode version used by your Azure pipeline should be XCode >= 14. Check the online docs about [requirements](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/5.x.x/intro#requirements-570).

Comment: Was your problem   solved? Did you specify your Xcode version on azure pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

In a similar question on how to clear the .pub-cache folder for flutter @CopsOnRoad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68380885) explains flutter has the following command for clearing the cache.

```
flutter pub cache clean
```

Run this command in a task before starting the actual build.